# How to deal: app does not see func from my dll

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, dll, masm, dllimport

Created a dll and an app to test proc from the dll.

The program counts number of repeating of a character.

Code:

dll:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none 

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 

.data
msg_string db 'Enter string: ', 0
msg_symbol db 'Enter symbol: ', 0
result db 'Count = %d', 0
str_modifier db '%s ', 0
sym_modifier db '%c', 0

.data
string db ?
symbol db ?

.code
DllEntry PROC hInstDLL:DWORD, reason:DWORD, reserved:DWORD  
    mov  eax, 1  
    ret 
DllEntry ENDP 

symbol_count PROC EXPORT 
    
    invoke crt_printf, OFFSET msg_string
    invoke crt_scanf, OFFSET str_modifier, OFFSET string
    invoke crt_printf, OFFSET msg_symbol
    invoke crt_scanf, OFFSET sym_modifier, OFFSET symbol
    
    xor esi, esi
    xor ecx, ecx

    mov ebx, OFFSET string
    mov al, symbol
loop1:
    cmp byte ptr [ebx + ecx], 0
    je endloop
    cmp al, byte ptr [ebx + ecx]
    jne next
    inc esi
next:
    inc ecx
    jmp loop1 
endloop:
    
    invoke crt_printf, OFFSET result, esi
    
    ret 

symbol_count ENDP 

End DllEntry
```

If i have much more better way to code this, please tell me it too. It's really hard to find needed information in the internet. Thank you.

test app:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none 

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 

LoadLibraryA proto LibName:DWORD
GetProcAddress proto hLib:DWORD, FunctionName:DWORD
FreeLibrary proto hLib:DWORD
ExitProcess proto uExitCode:DWORD

.data
LibName db 'Labor07.dll', 0
FunctionName db '_symbol_count@0', 0
DllNotFound db 'cannot find the dll', 0
AppName db 'Load explicit dll', 0
NotFound db 'Func is not found', 0
msg db 'Hello', 0
hLib dd ?
symbol_count_addr dd ?

.code
start:
    
    invoke LoadLibraryA, addr LibName
    .if eax == NULL
        invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, addr DllNotFound, addr AppName, MB_OK
    .else
        mov hLib, eax
        invoke GetProcAddress, hLib, addr FunctionName 
        .if eax == NULL
            invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, addr NotFound, addr AppName, MB_OK
        .else
            push offset msg 
            mov symbol_count_addr, eax 
            call [symbol_count_addr] 
        .endif
        invoke FreeLibrary, hLib 
    .endif 
    invoke ExitProcess, NULL 
end start
```

Result is MessageBox:

[image]

**UPDATE #1**

Result:

```
%path%>Project4
Enter string: asfasf
Enter symbol: Count = 1
%path%>
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
%path%>project4
Enter string: asfasfasf
a
Enter symbol: Count = 4
%path%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`labor07.dll` uses STDCALL (`.model flat, stdcall`). So, the names of the functions will be decorated: `_symbol_count@0`.

Change

```
FunctionName db 'symbol_count', 0
```

to

```
FunctionName db '_symbol_count@0', 0
```

Additionally, the function `symbol_count` must be exported.

Change

```
symbol_count PROC
```

to

```
symbol_count PROC EXPORT
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the program sees the procedure from now. But for some reason, after starting the program, it just closes with code 0. Maybe you know why? What i did wrong? Is proc bad, or maybe app...

Comment: @VolodimirPavlenko. The program works here, except the commonly known scanf issues ;-) and wrong counting. Your problems can have many causes. Have you set the subsystem to CONSOLE? If you ask a new question, please post the whole command lines (ml.exe and link.exe).

Comment: Yeah, i was wrong using windows subsystem. I had compiled and linked it using visual studio, that's why i can't post command lines. 
Can i ask what is wrong with my scanf? Uploaded result.

Comment: @VolodimirPavlenko: `scanf` is devilish. The first `ENTER` remains as `LF` (line feed = new line) in the stream and causes the immediate abort of the second `scanf`. Insert a space to clear white spaces (blanks, tabs, new lines): `str_modifier db '%s ', 0`. Remove `mov ecx, eax` for a proper counting.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working but the second printf feels extremely bad. Do you know what's happend? Uploaded new code and update #2 - new result.

Comment: @VolodimirPavlenko: As I said: `scanf` is devilish. Restore `str_modifier` and put the space in `sym_modifier`: `sym_modifier db ' %c', 0`.  --- `string db ?` reserves only **one** byte for the variable. Change it to `string db 256 DUP (?)` which reserves 256 bytes. I recommend taking a number divisible by 16.